# please help for fix CCJSqlParser exception

Tags: java, jsqlparser

I use CCJSqlParser to parse sql. I fase fatal  issues.

my java code as below

```
String sqlStr = "SELECT t1.Key as Key1,  t2.Key as Key2   FROM tabel1 as t1, tabel2 as t2 WHERE t1.Key = t2.Key";
Statement statement = CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(sqlStr);
```

Exception as below:

```
  12:11:27,608         INFO ParseSqlUtil:29 - start to parse SQL: SELECT t1.Key as Key1,  t2.Key as Key2   FROM tabel1 as t1, tabel2 as t2 WHERE t1.Key = t2.Key
    net.sf.jsqlparser.JSQLParserException12:11:27,650         INFO SparkTest:347 - excetption:null

        at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(CCJSqlParserUtil.java:51)
        at com.spark.ml.query.ParseSqlUtil.parseSqlToSparkQueryDto(ParseSqlUtil.java:30)
        at com.spark.ml.query.SparkTest.main(SparkTest.java:342)
    Caused by: net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.ParseException: Encountered " "." ". "" at line 1, column 10.
    Was expecting one of:
        <EOF> 
        "AS" ...
        "DO" ...
        "INTO" ...
        "FROM" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JSqlParser V0.9.2 your statement is parsed successfully.

```
String sqlStr = "SELECT t1.Key as Key1,  t2.Key as Key2   FROM tabel1 as t1, tabel2 as t2 WHERE t1.Key = t2.Key";
Statement statement = CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(sqlStr);   
System.out.println(statement.toString());
```

Gives the correct output:

```
SELECT t1.Key AS Key1, t2.Key AS Key2 FROM tabel1 AS t1, tabel2 AS t2 WHERE t1.Key = t2.Key
```

I assume the problem is the column name **key**, which is a **keyword** for JSqlParser. In recent versions more and more keywords were allowed for database object names.